# Queue based processing

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, redis, scalability

So I've been looking into building an application that relies on something similar to a messaging bus. The idea is to be extremely fault tolerant. I have a queue of tasks that need to be performed, and here are the steps that I believe would be the end goal in a queue based system.

- A/B server initially adds an item to the queue to be worked on.
- C server listening on queue sees a new item on the queue, and begins to work on it. I believe it should lock the item with a timeout, (If the server crashes, etc..., I need other workers to be able to work on it.)

One of two things happens now:

- C server fails to respond to said task, or it has taken long past the timeout, and the queue unlocks it and passes it to server D for processing

**- OR -**

- C server completes the task and ultimately removes the entry from the queue.

I was looking into different solutions, and I see a lot of people using REDIS as a backend for performing this operation, but it's queue is fairly simplistic. For example [`RPOPLPUSH`](http://redis.io/commands/rpoplpush) will remove the key from the queue. What happens if the server crashes? The queue now thinks it processed that item, and we have a lost task.

What steps are recommended for ensuring task completions, and noting task failures to be able to be reproccessed by another server? I intend to write the tasks in go and I'm open to using cloud services such as AWS.

Comment: RPOPLPUSH does dequeue and requeue to another list in one single atomic operation. If your process fails after this operation, nothing is lost (the item still exists in the other list). That said, achieving true guaranteed delivery with Redis is not trivial.

Comment: @DidierSpezia Do you recommend any other solutions?

Comment: A real queuing system is probably what you are looking for. See RabbitMQ, ActiveMQ, etc ... Here is a RabbitMQ Go client: https://github.com/streadway/amqp

Comment: @DidierSpezia Turn this into an answer, and I'll give you my thumbs up approval.

Comment: If you want a lightweight non-distributed work queue, beanstalkd would satisfy your requirements https://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/

Comment: If you need high performance and strong durability with fault tolerance you should include Kafka in the systems you are considering. Take a look at their design approach: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis is a basic component on which you can build a queuing system. That said, implementing a true guaranteed delivery system on top of Redis is not trivial, especially if you need a transactional behavior.

Here are some queuing systems implemented with Redis in various languages:

- http://python-rq.org/
- https://github.com/resque/resque
- https://github.com/ask/celery
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rpqueue

Similar things could be developed in Go, but when it comes to a true guaranteed delivery semantic, the devil is in the details.

You will probably be better served by a dedicated queuing system, such as RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ. While they are more complex, they offer more features, and probably better guarantees.

Here is a Go client for RabbitMQ: https://github.com/streadway/amqp

You might also be interested by looking at [disque](https://github.com/antirez/disque) (a dedicated queuing solution from Redis author), and the corresponding Go client at https://github.com/EverythingMe/go-disque

Finally, [beanstalkd](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/) is another lightweight solution; you can find the Go client at: https://github.com/kr/beanstalk

Comment: redis is additional work to setup and maintain. same for rabbitmq

Answer (score 1):

Going to probably state the obvious here, but SQS (http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) gives you what you need out of the box. You don't need to worry about managing the queueing system,  it will scale automatically for you, you are going to focus on writing the application.

you push messages to the queue. workers pull them from the queue, process them and ack the message when done. if the workers don't ack the message after the timeout you specify the message will be surfaced back to another worker.

Comment: I'm worried about the fact that multiple workers can receive a message with SQS. The point of a queue is one worker should be working on a task at one time. Not sure why amazon allows multiple workers to work on the same task.

Comment: Messages in SQS are given a timeout before they will be delivered to a second queue worker assuming the message was not processed (deleted).

Comment: @FrankerZ in normal operation you will have one worker working on the message. you need to handle 2 workers having the same message anyway  for the case the worker takes longer than the timeout and the message is given to the 2nd worker.

Comment: stepping back: guaranteeing exactly-once delivery is extremely hard (i.e. impossible) in the presence of faulty clients/network/server. the way to go would be to actually make the effects of the actions you are making idempotent so a 2nd client processing the same message would not cause harm. you can figure out the granularity of this (i.e. not all actions have to be idempotent as long as you have checkpoints)